# What will be the value of $\cos (n\pi x /l)$ for $x=0$?

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series

$\cos0 = 1$ but the value of the above expression is $1$.  How it is equal to $1$?  If $\cos0 =1$ then the value should be $n\pi/l$.

Comment: $n\pi \cos(0)/l=n \pi/l$ but $\cos(0n\pi/l)=\cos(0)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** the quantity were $\frac{cos(x)n\pi}{l}$ **then** the value would be $\frac{(1)n\pi}{l}= \frac{n\pi}{l}$.  But it is not!  You have parentheses around all of $n\pi x$ so the cosine function is applied to $n\pi x= n\pi 0= 0$.  The correct value is $\frac{cos(n\pi 0)}{l}= \frac{cos(0)}{l}= \frac{1}{l}$.

(**If** the parentheses were around the entire $\frac{n\pi x}{l}$ **then** the value would be $cos\left(\frac{n\pi 0}{l}\right)= cos(0)= 1$.)

Answer (score 0):

Here we assume $l\neq 0$. If $x=0$, we have that
$$
\cos(n\pi\times 0)/l=\cos(0)/l=1/l.
$$
If you mean $\cos(n\pi x/l)$, then, at $x=0$, we have
$$
\cos(n\pi\times 0/l)=\cos(0)=1.
$$